# Accounts-ui change text

Tags: meteor

Is there something wrong with my code? I can't get it to work on Meteor 1.0.

```
Template.header.rendered = function() {
  $('#login-sign-in-link').text('Login - german');
  $('.login-close-text').text('Close - german ');
};
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What kind are `'#login-sign-in-link'` and `'.login-close-text'`? Are those inputs?

If so, use rather `.val('text')`

Quoting documentation:

```
The .text() method cannot be used on input elements. For input field text, use the .val() method.
```